# How to disable errors in EF Core 3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

After upgrading Entity Framework from Core 2 to Core 3, a lot of our queries are broken. Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166970/migrating-from-ef-core-2-to-ef-core-3), I know what to do to fix it. The problem is that the errors come in runtime, and it will probably take several months of QA and development efforts to find them all (it's a large application).

Is there a way to turn on some *compatibility mode*, where EF would allow client evaluation, but show the warning, so that developers can fix them gradually?

Comment: You probably should have fixed all client-side evaluation warnings in EF2 first. However, 1) EF3 has limited client-side evaluation, i.e. in the final projection of a query, so by fixing all warnings you may do too much, and 2) EF3 will report new client-side evaluation problems EF2 didn't have. So all in all I'm afraid it's a painstaking process of checking many individual queries. Also, I'm not sure it's the right time to migrate to EF core 3, IMO it's still pretty immature.

Comment: @GertArnold - exactly! That's why I was hoping to get all these warnings in **EF3**. I really hope there will be some outcry that will force MS to put some kind of compatibility mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to turn on some compatibility mode, where EF would allow client evaluation, but show the warning, so that developers can fix them gradually?

Go back to EF Core 2 and configure a [warning for client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#previous-versions), and then upgrade to EF Core 3 once you've made all the fixes.

Comment: I am aware of this option... There are many reasons why we wanted to upgrade without fixing everything first (and given that the errors come only in runtime, it will be awhile until we are comfortable giving the build to the users). So, given *Microsoft* in your name, I can assume that the answer to *my* question is **NO**. Arrgh!

Comment: AFAIK there’s no way to make EF Core 3 allow client evaluation.  So other than downgrading, you’ll have to find all the queries though code analysts and/or testing.

Comment: I hoped for a different answer - but oh, well!