# The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query I am trying to run to populate an excel table. Here is the code for it.

```
                queryable = (from merchantTerminalDetails in context.Posh5ProdMerchantTerminalDetails
                             join merchantDetails in context.MerchantDetails
                             on merchantTerminalDetails.MerchantRecord equals merchantDetails.Id
                             join merchantContactDetails in context.Posh5ProdMerchantContactDetails
                             on merchantDetails.Id equals merchantContactDetails.MerchantRecord
                             where (merchantDetails.BypassAdviceVerification.ToString() == AdviceExemption &&
                             merchantDetails.BypassCreditVerification.ToString() == RefundExemption && merchantTerminalDetails.Tip.ToString() == TipAdjustment && merchantDetails.CoreBankingRecord.ToString() == Region)
                             select new OreDetails
                             {
                                 MerchantRecord = merchantTerminalDetails.MerchantRecord,
                                 LegalName = merchantDetails.LegalName,
                             
                                 PhoneNumber = merchantDetails.PhoneNumber,
                                 EmailAddress = merchantContactDetails.EmailAddress,
                                 TerminalId = merchantTerminalDetails.TerminalId,
                          


                             }).AsQueryable();
            }
```

What I have noticed is that when I remove `where (merchantDetails.BypassAdviceVerification.ToString() == AdviceExemption && merchantDetails.BypassCreditVerification.ToString() == RefundExemption && merchantTerminalDetails.Tip.ToString() == TipAdjustment && merchantDetails.CoreBankingRecord.ToString() == Region)` my query works and I can generate my excel file but unfortunately I can't filter with my parameters. Now I did look at this answer that I found on here [Migrating from EF Core 2 to EF Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166970/migrating-from-ef-core-2-to-ef-core-3) but I can't seem to figure out how to fix my where statement for it work correctly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the exception give you any detail about what was untranslatable? You say that if you remove the entire `where...` clause it works, have you tried removing sections of it and see what breaks and what doesn't? Which EF provider are you using e.g. SQL Server, Postgres, etc.?

Comment: For everything you've ToString'd, consider changing the type of your c# variables to match the type in the db rather than the other way round

Comment: @ZacFaragher its SQL server and I have tried removing sections of it. Anytime the where is there is breaks

Comment: @CaiusJard I am trying this now

Answer (score 1):

Depending on types of:

```
merchantDetails.BypassAdviceVerification
merchantDetails.BypassCreditVerification
merchantDetails.CoreBankingRecord
```

and the correlating values of AdviceExemption, RefundExcemption, and Region, you may need to cast the variables to match the underlying types.

For example if the properties in merchantDetails are Enumerations and the values you are passing into the method are strings coming from the UI with the name values of those enumerations, EF won't be able to translate an Enumeration (typically stored in the DB as an Int) to a string to compare.

Instead, translate the string values to their respective enumerations:

```
BypassAdviceVerification adviceExemptionEnum = Enum.Parse<BypassAdviceVerification>(AdviceExemption);
```

etc. for the enumerations then update the Linq expression to compare the enumerations:

```
merchantDetails.BypassAdviceVerification == adviceExemptionEnum
```

If they are not Enumerations but some other translation then translate the strings to match the Entity property types and use those for the comparisons rather than attempting to translate types within the Linq expressions.

Translations in the Linq expressions would work in EF Core 2 because EF Core 2 had client-side evaluation enabled by default. This would produce a warning when it resorted to client side evaluation, where EF Core 3 + disabled it by default, producing an error instead. You can opt to turn on client-side evaluation and your query will work as you expect, but client-side evaluation will lead to significant risk of serious performance issues. (Similar to poor implementation considerations around lazy loading)