# After updating from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 I am getting error: InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error can anyone help me, with this?

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Join( outer: DbSet, inner: o => EF.Property<Nullable>(o, "ListingId"), outerKeySelector: l => EF.Property<Nullable>(l, "Id"), innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Order, Listing>( Outer = o, Inner = i )) .Where(o => o.Outer.Accepted && !(o.Outer.Cancelled) && o.Outer.EndDateTime < DateTime.Now && o.Inner.Active)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The query, that I am trying to run is this:

```
return Task.FromResult((IResultList<ListingDTO>)new OrderByDistance(MapperFilter, ContextFactory.GetSharedContext().Set<Listing>().Where(listing =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) || listing.Name.Contains(keyword) || listing.Description.Contains(keyword)) &&
            (!categoryIds.Any() || categoryIds.Contains(listing.Category.Id)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipCode) || listing.User.ZipCode == zipCode) &&
            (!zipCodesInRegion.Any() || zipCodesInRegion.Contains(listing.User.ZipCode)) &&
            (priceFrom == null || listing.Prices.Any(e => e.Amount >= priceFrom && (priceTo == null || e.Amount <= priceTo))) &&
            (priceTo == null || listing.Prices.Any(e => e.Amount <= priceTo && (priceFrom == null || e.Amount >= priceFrom))) &&
            !listing.Deleted &&
            listing.Active &&
            !listing.ImportedNotActivated &&
            listing.Category.Active &&
            listing.User.Active &&
            ((forSale && listing.IsForSale) || !forSale)
            ), latitude, longitude));
```

I tried adding: `AsEnumerable()`, `AsAsyncEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, or `ToListAsync()`, but none of them are working.

**Answer**

I was getting this error, because the listing do contain

```
public bool IsForSale => SalesPrice != null || SalesPrice > 0;
```

After changing the query to it is working:

```
return Task.FromResult((IResultList<ListingDTO>)new OrderByDistance(MapperFilter, ContextFactory.GetSharedContext().Set<Listing>().Where(listing =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword) || listing.Name.Contains(keyword) || listing.Description.Contains(keyword)) &&
            (!categoryIds.Any() || categoryIds.Contains(listing.Category.Id)) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipCode) || listing.User.ZipCode == zipCode) &&
            (!zipCodesInRegion.Any() || zipCodesInRegion.Contains(listing.User.ZipCode)) &&
            (priceFrom == null || listing.Prices.Any(e => e.Amount >= priceFrom && (priceTo == null || e.Amount <= priceTo))) &&
            (priceTo == null || listing.Prices.Any(e => e.Amount <= priceTo && (priceFrom == null || e.Amount >= priceFrom))) &&
            !listing.Deleted &&
            listing.Active &&
            !listing.ImportedNotActivated &&
            listing.Category.Active &&
            listing.User.Active &&
            ((forSale && (SalesPrice != null || SalesPrice > 0)) || !forSale)
            ), latitude, longitude));
```

Comment: Did you go to the link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating from EF Core 2 to EF Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166970/migrating-from-ef-core-2-to-ef-core-3)

Comment: .NET Core 3 reached End Of Life last year. You should be migrating to .NET 6, supported until 2024, not a dead version. Yes, there were significant differences in the migration from EF Core 2 to 3 because EF Core 2 was so limited it used client-side evaluation to handle queries it couldn't translate to SQL. EF Core 2.1 at least generated warnings every time it did this. EF Core 3 throws errors so you can fix the problems

Comment: I tried the link and also the recommendations from the link, but none of them fixed my problem, I am still getting the error.

Comment: Without the query it's impossible to say what's wrong. The query is definitely wrong, but EF Core 2 covered up the problems. If your code is actually trying to JOIN entities explicitly by generating a `TransparentIdentifier` instance, there are multiple bugs involved: 1) trying to use EF Core as embedded SQL instead of an ORM and 2) using constructs that can't be translated to SQL. You could have avoided that if `Order` had a `Listings` property, in which case EF itself would generate the JOIN and return an `Order` and its `Listing`s

Comment: this bit: `innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Order, Listing>(` looks like code that cannot be translated to SQL. Prior to EF Core 3 it would cause a warning and download all the results and run that bit of the query in .NET not in the DB. EF Core 3+ now errors when this happens.

Comment: As for `.Where(` inside the JOIN, was this an attempt to implement a filtered Include? This is [supported in EF Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include). I think it was first added in EF Core 5.

Comment: Where is exact LINQ query?

Comment: Sorry I just posted it into the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking your code, if the entity Listing do contain => expressions in one of the properties.
The lambda expression is evaluated not on a server side, but on a user, and you can use it in LINQ expression and that's why You are getting the: InvalidOperationException.

Comment: This seems to fix my problem: I have property in code: public bool IsForSale => SalesPrice != null || SalesPrice > 0;
And I changed it in the LINQ expressions, and it fix the Exception.